# How does Asp.net MVC display server error messages if error placement function is used instead of @Html.ValidationSummaryFor()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to know is this possible in **Asp.net MVC**. I understand all the **unobtrusive validation** stuffs, so please don't post any links for unobtrusive validation.
Following are the steps:

1. Create a ErrorPlacement Function (`jquery.validate` out of the box)
   in javascript for displaying Validation Errors
2. Create some custom validation attributes in the model
3. Disable the Javascript
4. Post to Server, now assume that the `ModelState` is Invalid, we
   return the Model State with errors.

My question is, now the javascript is disabled and i am not using `@Html.ValidationSummaryFor()` for displaying error messages. I only have errorplacement function which was working great if the javascript was enabled. Is there any way to display error messages that would have displayed if i had errorplacement function?

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: well [@Html.ValidationMessageFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor(v=vs.118).aspx) will give you individual field error messages if that is what you mean

Comment: @Rhumborl If we use that i know some how out of the box error messages gets displayed. But i am not using that. I have lots of messages to be displayed in different formats so i use errorplacement function. If we disable javascript, how do we display that kind of messages?

Comment: In that case, you should post your existing `ErrorPlacement` function. If javascript is disabled, you are most likely just going to have to replicate the js code into c#

Comment: So let me get this straight.. you remove all the non-javascript error generation, then disable javascript, and wonder why it's not displaying errors?

Comment: If javascript is disabled, using an `ErrorPlacement` function is pointless (its javascript!). You could get the list of errors from `ModelState` and assign it to a `ViewBag` or a view model property and then display them in the view.

Comment: @erik well i am not wondering, i want to know is there any way i can do it.

Comment: @ Stephen please read the question carefully before commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC's only method for displaying errors is using Html.ValidationSummary(For) or Html.ValidationMessage(For).  These create the wrapper containers in which error messages are displayed, either for JavaScript, or server-side postback messages.

Regardless, unless you're going to write your own Helper (or equivalent), you have to use these.